# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Classes' of undefined

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, httpclient

I am new to the Angular framework and TypeScript. I am trying to make a GET request following [this tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/http-with-angular-quick-start/#How-to-Make-a-GET-Request). It works for me, but when I am trying to make another GET request as shown below, I get the next error:

```
AppComponent.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Classes' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (AppComponent.html:7)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14735)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13849)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:14635)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:11619)
at eval (core.js:5918)
```

I have this app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, onInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  posts: any;
  Classes: string;

  readonly ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/[path]';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
  }
  getPosts() {
      this.posts = this.http.get(ROOT_URL + "/getClasses");
  }
  }
```

In app.component.html:

```
<button (click)="getPosts()">Get Posts</button>
<div>
  {{ posts.Classes | json }}
  </div>
```

And the JSON I try to get is:

```
{"Classes":["Element1","Element2","Element3"]}
```

After I added the line for calling getPosts(), I still get the same error.

Comment: Where do you call getPosts()?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the div is rendered before you get the data from the get, and then `posts` is still undefined.
Add `*ngIf="posts"` to the div so it won't be rendered if `posts` is undefined.

Comment: Nice catch.. But OP doesn't seem to be calling `getPosts()` method anywhere in his code.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once, as it just solved the problem I was having with my unit tests

Answer (score 0):

When the component initialises, posts is still undefined.
The safe navigation operator should solve your problem

`<div>
  {{ posts?.Classes | json }}
</div>`